# .htaccess file not running and internal server error

Tags: 14.04, apache2, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am using ubuntu 14.04 and have LAMP environment. I have one of the project in dir **/var/www/html/project1** . It can't access the **.htaccess** file for rewriting url rules.

For that i have to change in **/etc/apache2/apache2.conf** file

```
   <Directory /var/www/>
          Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
          AllowOverride All       # change None to All
          Order allow,deny
          allow from all
          Require all granted
   </Directory>
```

But after this change my Apache server gives an error "Internal Server error"

And If I'll change '**AllowOverride None**' then site is running correctly But .htaccess file doen't work.

Comment: Is rewrite enabled? `sudo a2enmod rewrite` followed by `sudo service apache2 restart` . If yes, then I think the issue is in your .htaccess file. Perhaps add its content to your question.

Comment: @Doug, I think you need to put that comment as an answer. And it should be the accepted answer too. I know I'd vote +1 for your answer!

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. After searching a lot I have found that @Doug Smythies's way perfectly work for me. Up vote.

So I go to the terminal and run the following code:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
sudo service apache2 restart
```

And that's it. Hope this will help others.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Directory /var/www/html/project1>
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride All
  Order allow,deny
  allow from all
  Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Remove project 1 from your directory name and then solve the problem only one word